# .net Dynamic Reference but still have intellisense

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Our team works on Modules that have dependencies to different assemblies.  E.g. We have a EmailClient Module that uses one set to assemblies for one particular build and another set of completely different assemblies for another build.  That's because depending on the customer we integrated to different backends.

We want to keep one source tree for the EmailClient and make sure the "Latest" version always works for all customers.  Our challenge here, is to not distribute unnecessary assemblies to one set of customers.  As they get picky and ask what all these other files are for.

This is causing the following error and is very difficult to catch in one place:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly.

Does .Net provide such a feature where we can add reference to all sorts of assemblies, but not distribute some of them?

Comment: If you don't distribute an assembly with the application, then the code can't use that assembly.  If the code isn't using it, why have a reference to it?

Comment: This seems like a candidate for a plugin-style or provider-style architecture where you would implement a standard interface to the EmailClient and then use a configuration setting to give the concrete class(es) to implement the EmailClient's details. Whether that's a DI file, or the app.config, or MEF is implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin, Jeroen also mentioned MEF, will be looking at this.

Comment: @David, we want one source that caters for different customers.  CustomerA may have a Avaya backend with its set of dependant dlls, CustomerB may have a Exchange backend with its set of dependant dlls.  We don't want to include Avaya related dlls for CustomerB.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at a plugin architecture like *Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

This way you can expand your current application without creating dependencies to assemblies.

Even if you're not planning to implement MEF. It will gives ideas and *new* ways to think, about how to implement it your own.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, will be checking out MEF.